# Can comments be used in the .gemspec file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I'm making a Ruby gem, and I want to put comments in the file. Would this be allowed, or would it mess up the gem? My code:

```rb
# test

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'My Gem' # Add a better name
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.summary     = "Summary of my gem"
  s.description = "More detailed description" # Maybe a tiny bit more detailed?
  s.authors     = ["Me"]
  s.email       = 'foo.bar@example.net' # Please don't email me, as I rarely look at my email
  s.files       = ["lib/myGem.ruby"] # Change to .rb
  s.homepage    =
    'https://rubygems.org/gems/foobar'
end

# Add s.license

=begin
foo
bar
=end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a Ruby file. Any legal Ruby syntax will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm making a Ruby gem, and I want to put comments in the file. Would this be allowed, or would it mess up the gem?

Like most programming languages, Ruby has comments. In fact, Ruby has two kinds of comments:

- *Single-line comments* start with the token `#` and end with the end of the line:

  ```ruby
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby
  # Shebang lines are just interpreted as comments, which is clever.
  some_code # This is a comment.

  # So is this.

  foo.bar.
    # Comments are allowed in lots of places.
    baz(
      # And here.
      23, # And here.
      42,
      # And here.
      :foo
  )
  # Even here.
  .quux
  ```
- *Multi-line comments* start with the token `=begin` at the beginning of a line and end with the token `=end` at the beginning of a line:

  ```ruby
  some_code
  =begin This is a comment.
  This is still the same comment.
  So is this.
  This is not the end of the comment: =end

  But this is:
  =end
  ```

If you want to know all the gory details, I recommend reading:

- [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html), section 8.5 *Comments*
- [`language/comment_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/comment_spec.rb) of [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/)
- Section 2.1 *Lexical structure* of [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177)
- The [*Code Comments*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/comments_rdoc.html) sub-section in the [Ruby Syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax_rdoc.html) section of the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/)
- The introductory parts of [*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/)

Comment: It should be noted that the Ruby style guide doesn't recommend the use of block comments. "Don’t use block comments. They cannot be preceded by whitespace and are not as easy to spot as regular comments.". Block comments were also largely motivated by RDTool which is obsolete. https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#rd-block-comments

Answer (score 0):

The `.gemspec` and `Gemfile` are actually just plain old Ruby files and the same syntax rules apply as in any other Ruby code. Unlike other more verbose languages (cough cough Java) Ruby is actually very well suited to writing configuration and you'll more often then not find it used instead of XML, JSON or YAML files.

They just don't have an `.rb` extension - as to why then thats probally a question that only the original authors can answer to. Another example of this same phenomenon is Rack's `config.ru`.